# What are the URL for the pages using PropelPager?

Tags: symfony1, propel

I have an action with this code:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(sfGuardUserProfilePeer::USER_ID, sfGuardUserGroupPeer::USER_ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->add(sfGuardUserGroupPeer::GROUP_ID, 2 );

$this->pager = new PropelPager($c, 'sfGuardUserProfilePeer', 'doSelect', $page = 2, $rowsPerPage = 1);
```

And in the corresponding template this:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($pager->getResult() as $book): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $book->getName() ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->getSurname() ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

When i call the action I get the first page with the first results, but what is the URL for the page 2 ?

Thanks!

sf 1.4/pr 1.5

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to correct your code:

```
$this->pager = new PropelPager($c, 'sfGuardUserProfilePeer', 'doSelect', $page, $rowsPerPage);
```

Secondly, only you define how page number is handled in your action. I'd prefer `page` parameter in URL:

```
// $request - a sfWebRequest object passed to your action
$page = $request->getParameter('page', 1); // first page by default
$this->pager = new PropelPager($c, 'sfGuardUserProfilePeer', 'doSelect', $page = 2, $rowsPerPage = 1);
```

And then you have to manully generate links to pages in your view:

```
<table>
<?php if ($pager->getNbResults()): ?>
    <?php foreach ($pager->getResults() as $book): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $book->getName() ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->getSurname() ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</table>

<?php if ($pager->haveToPaginate()): ?>
  display pagination here and generate "uri/?page=N" links
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, all available pages are retrieved by `$pager->getLinks()`. Result is array.

Further reading:

- [How to paginate a list in Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/pager). It's ok for 1.4 too.
- [sfPropelPager API](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfPager)

Hope that helps.